# How to rotate HDMI display with Android Things

Tags: android-things

Is there any way to rotate the screen? I mean, I would like to rotate my monitor 90º, I already tried to add the screen-rotation on the manifest, lcd_rotation and display_rotation both on boot/config.txt but without success.

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do a workaround for this issue while there's no **beautiful** way.

The idea was to rotate your activity layout.

```
    public static void rotateScreen(final RelativeLayout layout, final Activity activity) {

        Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int w = size.x;
        int h = size.y;

        layout.setRotation(90.0f);
        layout.setTranslationX((w - h) / 2);
        layout.setTranslationY((h - w) / 2);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = layout.getLayoutParams();
        lp.height = w;
        lp.width = h;
        layout.setLayoutParams(lp);
        layout.requestLayout();
    }
```

My main layout is a Relative, but you can generalize and do it for any one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the orientation of your activity. In your manifest.xml, add the following line in the activity section:
`android:screenOrientation="portrait"`

Comment: Actually this does not work...  I tried as I said in the question.