# How to rotate Raspberry Pi official display to portrait in android things OS

Tags: raspberry-pi3, android-things

I've been trying to write my app to change the orientation of the UI to that of vertical from horizontal in android things running on a Raspberry Pi 3. 
I have tried using this command , but app keeps on crashing

```
 // Lock orientation in portrait mode
 screenManager.lockRotation(ScreenManager.ROTATION_90);
```

Comment: This one worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46670917/how-to-rotate-hdmi-display-with-android-things

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thanks!